# slidingExpiration doesn't seem with work with ASP.NET MVC APIs when working with SPAs

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, iis

My users, when on a SPA page, are getting logged out after a couple of hours. Though, if they use the older postback forms, they never time out. So you have context, I have included enough code to provide context for the description of the issue on the bottom.

Web.config for authentication

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="480" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="~" ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework40"/>
</authentication>
```

My api controller

```
namespace my.Controllers
{
    public class ApiMotionController : ApiController
    {   
        [Authorize(Roles = "Mover"]
        public IQueryable<Motions> Get()
```

JavaScript code

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('app')
    .controller('MotionManager', ['$scope', '$http', buildMotionManager]);

function buildMotionManager($scope, $http) {
    /*Static Members*/
    $scope._whoami = 'MotionManager'; //Used for troubleshooting controller

    /*Initialization Code*/
    getMotions($scope, $http)();

    /*Scope methods*/
    $scope.refreshMotionsList = getMotions($scope, $http);
    $scope.addMotion = addMotion($scope, $http);
    $scope.playMotion = playMotion($scope, $http);

}

function getMotions($scope, $http){
    return function(){
        $http.get('/api/getMotions')
             .succeed(function(data){
                 $scope.motionList = data;
             })
             .error(function(data){
                 console.log('FAIL', data);
             });
    };
}

function addMotion($scope, $http){
    //stub. Code not shown here.
};
function playMotion($scope, $http){
    //stub. Code not shown here.
};

})();
```

There my be typos in the above code, since I retyped it from my original while sanitizing.

The code does work as expected, but the problem is that after hours of working, suddenly all web API calls are failing with a 401 error. That is, they are all acting like the user is now de-authenticated.

As above, I cannot duplicate this issue when I am using web forms, or even MVC forms, and re-posting whole pages. It is only when I am using SPA style coding. I haven't tried other SPA frameworks, since I have 6 months of angular directed code in this project, switching isn't an option.

I have considered putting an iframe, with a timer to fire off in the background against a form object, just to trick the browser into generating a proper form postback. I want to avoid doing that, because it seems to hacky.

The only other key issue I have found is that I am seeing a bunch of schannel errors being logged into my application event log on the IIS server. They are all 10,10 which isn't well documented. The 10 series is well documented outside of 10,10. But none of those suggestions seem to work, or are even relevant.

Server is IIS 7.5 and I have tried this on IIS 8.

**Application Log Errors:**

- A fatal alert was generated and sent to the remote endpoint. This may result in termination of the connection. The TLS protocol defined fatal error code is 10. The Windows SChannel error state is 10.

  - Error State: 10, Alert Description: 10
- A fatal alert was generated and sent to the remote endpoint. This may result in termination of the connection. The TLS protocol defined fatal error code is 40. The Windows SChannel error state is 1205.
- An TLS 1.2 connection request was received from a remote client application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client application are supported by the server. The SSL connection request has failed.

**Discovery**

Error Code 40 means that there is a handshake issue. Since State Management is custom for my platform, I decided to change it to inproc. So far, I have seen the error log reduce in new error frequency, but disappear. However, I am still testing for the 401 issue.

**Post discovery follow up**

Had the certs re-issued, and the *schannel* errors cleared, but the problem remained.

I had started exploring the header information with a fine tooth comb, even if it means that I had to add custom header information to accompany my server calls.

I have now included in all $http calls `withCredentials: true`, which has brought my failure rate down to around 15%. that means that the failures are down to once or twice a day.

I started watching my 'auth' cookie on the client, and something confusing happens occasionally. The cookie will change without prompt, then it has changed back. Almost like the session is bouncing from current, to a new one, then back to current. So I have killed my cleanup process on the session table on the server, and see what I am getting there.

I had also been checking the system logs for exceptions, or SQL timeouts, and nothing.

Started to convert all controllers to MVC controllers, but I have hit conversion problems after conversion problems, including the use of jSON serializer. I still don't understand the decision to stick with the MS serializer when the JSON.NET one work so much better.

**Current Status**

The last change I made was to add `filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());` to my `FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters` function.

Everything is still failing. After investigating the IIS logs I am still seeing everything getting de-authenticated.

- FF on Windows - **Fail**
- Chrome on Windows - **Fail**
- Chrome on Droid - **Fail**
- Safari on iPad - **Fail**
- IE on Windows - **Fail**

**12/10 Discovery**

I have found the real problem. The authentication in MVC controllers are just not compatible with the web API controllers. So when I authenticate with the MVC controller, the web API controllers basically ignore it, and eventually time out on the authentication.

**Latest Discovery**

Apparently when the asp.net worker process shut down, and restarted, it would get a false flag that the database schema didn't exists. So I removed the check, and all reads and writes started working fine. It is interesting that the api controller would forge a new cookie when the mvc controller would fail the authentication. It was like it was creating a new provider instance. However, I couldn't find a 2nd instance, so I have to assume the existing provider was being duplicated.

**Fix that is being tested**

Now that I have removed the DB test, I am now testing the issue in long run tests. Each long run is longer than the worker process stays alive, but shorter than the session timeout.

**Cornerstone of finding this bug**

Apparently IIS Express was hiding the bug in that it seems to act without an external worker process. So I moved the test environment to my local IIS server.

Comment: This does not seem like it is an angular issue since it is dealing with authentication through WebApi. How are you re-authenticating once you've timed out?

Comment: One of the reasons why it would work with web forms/mvc forms is due to the server managing your state/cookies. You've since decoupled this (with WebApi and Angular) and need to re-authenticate with the server from what I can tell.

Comment: livepo, Once they are logged out I force them to navigate to the login screen, and re-authenticate.

So restful calls aren't maintaining session cookies? I thought that the 5 verbs were full implementation of the service verbs. At the server, I can access the cookie in the apicontroller.

Comment: Please take a look at the following [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/784106/AngularJS-Token-Authentication-using-ASP-NET-Web-A). Also this article may [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260513/angularjs-and-web-api-form-authentication). or even [this](http://www.seankenny.me/blog/2013/10/02/angularjs-formsauthentication-in-net-land/)

Comment: The following articles are all related to WebApi form authentication with AngularJS and can describe the way you will have to implement it. You have the right idea, but i'm thinking that it is not being handled correctly in your C#. The way it will need to be handled is going to be different from web forms/mvc because of the complete separation of client-side and server-side.

Comment: @livepo, All of those assume that there is a problem with the authentication, or that I am authenticating using Angular. As I stated, the authentication is being done in standard forms. The problem is that the expiration isn't extending on every call back to the server. As a test, I moved the application back to my internal server, (No SSL), and the problem goes away. So the problem is narrowed down to the SSL or the Public server. :( Unless someone knows what the new information I posted above means, I may not be able to resolve.

Comment: SSL works for all other apps except the one you have created angular, correct? Also for error codes, see this [list](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2012/10/06/ssl-tls-alert-protocol-amp-the-alert-codes.aspx)

Comment: Also here is a [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3a2d2eec-000d-432a-abd7-6b965268c671/an-tls-10-connection-request-was-received-from-a-remote-client-application-but-none-of-the-cipher?forum=sqlreportingservices) to the last error you have received

Comment: Looks like we are now on the same track. I have just looked at that last link, and forwarded its info to my server manager. The blog post was the first place I have seen that explained what 10,10 was, unexpected_message, always fatal. Had MS put that in a better place, I would have found it better. :(

Comment: I have also made one other change, due to what I found, and you also found, from the last link, I have removed my custom session manager, and switched to the inproc. If this works, then it is a case where I need to change how I do session management. I manage TLS Handshake in my session manager. So if it is incompatible for some reason, I should have immediate positive results by doing this.

Comment: This is good news! Let me know if that helped

Comment: I am on the right tract, but I don't have the final answer yet. Since I moved the auth to InProc, and set the InProc timeout to be about an hour, the user's UI times out in an hour. Since this application has a life of 8 hours, 1 shift, I will move to SQL State manager, and have it store the states for 8 hours. That will also restore my ability to have a cluster of servers if needed. Will post final fix when I come across.

Comment: It looks like I may have been wrong about the session manager, but I have added `withCredentials: true` to the configuration of the $http service, and I see more data in the header. So I am testing that now.

Comment: Because of my further discoveries, and @livepo's comments, I have changed the title to reflect reality better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are several issues that were causing my problem, each one broken down here:

1. IIS Express wasn't closing sessions the same way that full IIS would.

   1. So I moved the application to my local IIS, and added logging to everything.
2. ASP.NET worker process would launch new provider instance every time the API Controllers were called.

   1. This would cause a new schema check per call. MVC controllers would only cause this check once per initial launch.
   2. Since my provider is marries to my application schema, I just disabled the schema check.
3. Angular must be told to marshal the cookies.

   1. So I added: `cfg: { withCredentials: true, responseType: "json" }`
   2. the response type was to cover the occasional issue where I would see 'text/text'. Now I always see 'application/json'. This seems to be a browser issue, mostly with IE.
4. I also had to add `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` to my register method of my WebApiConfig class.

Using all of this, I was able to discover that the core of the problem was that every api call was causing my security provider to re-test the schema, which my MVC controllers are set to suppress that test after first load. The test always fails, because I had to expand a couple of tables, but I didn't need the models changed.

Resolution: I removed the test from the provider. Since the provider is strongly tied into the rest of the application, it didn't seem logical to keep treating it as a typical ASP.NET Membership provider. And that was the top feature that I didn't need.

Second benefit, I gained back a little bit of performance.

Comment: `responseType: "json"` should be used sparingly, especially if you return un wrapped strings, guids, INTs or other single values.

If the return body looks like `"some value"` rather than `{"value":"some value"}`, then `responseType: "json"` will fail on Chrome and Firefox.